# Open datagrid behind the scenes and work with it

Tags: database, vb.net, datagrid

Is it possible to open the datagrid behind the scenes and work with it? Just like opening a database. Any example, explaining or code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what you meant by "behind the scenes" ?

Comment: Must not show on the screen

Comment: what kind of work you need to do with that datagrid ?

Comment: I want to read the number of rows in the datagrid without opening on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work with the [DataTable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-vbnet) object.  This will allow you to minipulate that data without having to worry about it being displayed in a view.  Then if you want to display it you can bind later on.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("column1")
    dt.Rows.Add("row1")

    If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

        For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim column As String = dt.Rows(x)(0).ToString
            MessageBox.Show(column)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. How do I get the first column of each row in the table when i user DataTable? Ive tried this code but I get this error "there is not row at position 0". Heres my code: `If modAdapter.ModulesCountRow() <> 0 Then
                For x As Integer = 0 To modAdapter.ModulesCountRow()
                    Dim column As String = modDataset.modules.Rows(x)(0).ToString
                    MsgBox(column)
                Next
            End If`

Comment: I updated my answer, it should get you what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your datagrid invisible (during the time which you don't want to show it), or permanent.

But I find it strange that you don't want to see the result.
This make me wonder if the number of rows which you want to read, can't be handled by code.